# Problem with ajax - sending everythink to linkbar like GET option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

a problem with ajax because everytime when I want to click submit button then shows everythink in linkbar like 127.0.0.1:8000/?token[...] etc with every parameter it looks like method GET in form html but I haven't any method there. I think my code don't even try to execute Routes because I haven't any issue with json or database

```
$('#saveBtn').on('click', function () {
        ajax: {
        url: "{{route('res.Add')}}",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
        return {
            _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
            search: params.term // search term
        };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
        return {
            results: response
        };
        },
        cache: true
    }
    });
```

///BUTTON

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn">Add</button>
```

And Route link

```
Route::post("/res/Add", "ResController@addRes")->name('res.Add');
```

Comment: you have to prevent the click event first. `$('#saveBtn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: It still not execute any code from route link

Comment: use your browser dev console's network tab to check if the ajax request is working or not.

Comment: You're not [calling ajax as a function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you're just defining it as an object.

Comment: @El_Vanja so what should I do then? You mean to type $.ajax before that?

Comment: if you are not using any library like autocomplete search ya you have to write it like that.